# rtl_tabSelectedTextColor or anyother xml part of RecyclerTabLayout is not working

Tags: android

the three lines of com.nshmura.recyclertablayout.RecyclerTabLayout is working but remaining xml part is not.

the source i used is: "https://github.com/nshmura/RecyclerTabLayout"

changing the xml values

```
<com.nshmura.recyclertablayout.RecyclerTabLayout
    android:id="@+id/recycler_tab_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    rtl_tabIndicatorColor="?attr/colorAccent"
    rtl_tabIndicatorHeight="2dp"
    rtl_tabBackground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    rtl_tabTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
    rtl_tabSelectedTextColor="?android:textColorPrimary"
    rtl_tabMinWidth="72dp"
    rtl_tabMaxWidth="264dp"
    rtl_tabPaddingStart="12dp"
    rtl_tabPaddingTop="0dp"
    rtl_tabPaddingEnd="12dp"
    rtl_tabPaddingBottom="0dp"
    rtl_tabPadding="0dp"/>
```

Unknown attribute rtl_tabSelectedTextColor less... (Ctrl+F1) 
Inspection info: This inspection highlights unknown XML attributes in Android resource files and AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the app prefix before every attribute as below.
This is actually not specified properly in the documentation.

```
<com.nshmura.recyclertablayout.RecyclerTabLayout
android:id="@+id/recycler_tab_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="48dp"
app:rtl_tabIndicatorColor="?attr/colorAccent"
app:rtl_tabIndicatorHeight="2dp"
app:rtl_tabBackground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
app:rtl_tabTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
app:rtl_tabSelectedTextColor="?android:textColorPrimary"
app:rtl_tabMinWidth="72dp"
app:rtl_tabMaxWidth="264dp"
app:rtl_tabPaddingStart="12dp"
app:rtl_tabPaddingTop="0dp"
app:rtl_tabPaddingEnd="12dp"
app:rtl_tabPaddingBottom="0dp"
app:rtl_tabPadding="0dp"/>
```